# select from table depend on value from two column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this

```
id | question | unit | lesson
1  | how       |  1   |   2
2  | when      |  1   |   3
3  | where     |  1   |   4
4  | what      |  2   |   1
5  | how many  |  2   |   2
6  | how much  |  3   |   1
7  | how long  |  3   |   3
8  | how this  |  3   |   4
9  | what is   |  3   |   6
```

and i have a unit and lesson check boxes , user select from it 
how can i select from table depend on user select
ex : user select (1,3),(3,4)

my code

```
SELECT * FROM `prim_3` WHERE (unit IN ( '1' , '3' )) AND (lesson IN ( '3','4'))
```

Comment: What is not working with that code? Seems fine to me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will also return 1,4 and 3,1. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `prim_3` WHERE 
  (unit = '1' AND lesson = '3') OR
  (unit = '3' AND lesson = '4')
```

This matches either (OR) of the exact combinations defined between parentheses.

Because of [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), you may not strictly need the parentheses, but I like to use them in situations like this, because it makes it very clear which conditions belong together.